# ubuntu Network not working

Tags: wireless, network-manager, ethernet

I have an HP laptop. I'm trying to connect to the internet. But I cant seem to connect by both LAN and Wireless. Wireless doesnt list my connection. In fact the 'Wi-Fi Networks' button is deactivated. While connecting through ethernet, it detects presence of connection, but after sometime, stays idle with no connection.
There doesnt seem to be any problem while connecting through windows in dual boot mode in same laptop.

Here are the results of `ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:bf:9c:0a:ce:7d  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1  
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000  
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback    
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0  
         inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host  
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1  
          RX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
          TX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0   
          RX bytes:11377 (11.3 KB)  TX bytes:11377 (11.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:29:af:94:27:59     
          inet addr:10.10.0.1  Bcast:10.10.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0  
          inet6 addr: fe80::7629:afff:fe94:2759/64 Scope:Link  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1  
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
          TX packets:46 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000   
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:8637 (8.6 KB)
```

Here are the results of `lspci | grep Wireless lspci | grep Ethernet`:

```
0a:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter  

08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

Here are the results of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`:

```
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.   RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2337]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169  
--
0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]  
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]  
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Here are the results of `rfkill list all`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  
1: phy0: Wireless LAN  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `sudo ifdown eth0`
2. Configure static ip address in `/etc/network/interfaces` or put auto dhcp.
3. Run `sudo ifup eth0`
4. Run `/etc/init.d/networking restart`

Comment: Sorry. i couldnt understand your solution. Can you be a bit more elaborate..?